# GCM to FCM for Chrome extensions

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I've been using the Gmail, Calendar and Drive APIs to get [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) in my Chrome extension via chrome.gcm.onMessage

But chrome.gcm is being [deprecated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=831532) and I'm assuming chrome.gcm.onMessage will stop working in April. Is there any alternative solution? I'm trying to use the Firebase JS client as a service worker, I'm getting messages to the setBackgroundMessageHandler but they are forcing the display of desktop notifications! I want to process the data messages myself just as I did with chrome.gcm.onMessage

manifest.json

```
"manifest_version": 2,
...
"gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
...
```

background.js

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('js/firebase-messaging-sw.js')

// Also how does this all play in now with FCM...
chrome.instanceID.getToken({
   authorizedEntity: [MY_GCM_SENDER_ID],
   scope: "GCM"
}).then(token => {

});
```

js/firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: [MY_GCM_SENDER_ID] // Same I used to use with chrome.instanceID.getToken I guess???
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    var notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      icon: '/images/icon128.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
  });
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @JosephWang So the API is still working, I had reached out to Simeon via the extensions forum and he said it would continue. Note the firebase code alternative above would not work anymore with MV3 and the service workers.

Comment: I think the popup.html can recieve FCM push event, I just don't know where to register the `firebase-messaging.sw.js` since both v3 and popup.html can both register a service worker.

Comment: Wait, did you managed to get 'setBackgroundMessageHandler' to work? Then you're ready to go! You just need to switch your FCM push event to a data type rather than the one having 'notification' payload, and then you can handle your data as usual.

Comment: The setBackgroundMessageHandler did not work because it requires a visual notification and I need only data.

Comment: You can call `self.addEventListener('push', callback)` __before__ `firebase.messaging()`, this will guarantee work.